# Imputation in normalized signals

Tags: missing-data, normalization, data-imputation

I'm currently analyzing a variety of signals. The problem I have is that I have several "missing" values. These "missing" values represent the absence of signal, they are not errors in sampling or something else.

So it seems important to keep them when performing the data analysis. However, I'm unsure about the best way to include them in the analysis.

I have devised 2 main options, both using standardized data:

1. To transform continuous data into categorical data using the standard deviations of the normalized data, and adding a category for "no-signal".
2. Replacing all missing values by a z-score of -4 or -6.

I would like to ask about your opinion (pros and cons) of using one of these methods.

PS: Maybe is worth to say that my data are right skewed ranging from ~ (-2) to (+5) SD.